# Connection of Bootstrap and Rails search form

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on project where I am currently building the landing page and I'd like to have a search bar in the center

I watched a GoRails tutorial for the functionality and everything is working but I have problems to connect Bootstrap with Rails for the layout so that the search button is right next to the form and connected to it. Currently there seems to be a line break and the button is in another line. I already tried several different classes but haven't found a solution so far. Can anyone give me a hint where the problem is?

This is the code I am working with for the search bar:

```
<div id="landing-search-input">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
           <%= form_with url: search_path, local: true, method: :get, html: { class: "form-inline" } do |form| %>
               <%= form.text_field :q, placeholder: "Search", size: 40, data: { behavior: "autocomplete" }, class: "form-control" %>
               <%= form.button "Search", class: "btn btn-outline-success" %>
           <% end %>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to manage form.text and form.button, especially since you gave the form-control to form-text it will hold all the line provided and push next object to below it, here is the correction that may be can work

```
<div id="landing-search-input">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
           <%= form_with url: search_path, local: true, method: :get, html: { class: "form-inline" } do |form| %>
               <div class="row form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <%= form.text_field :q, placeholder: "Search", size: 40, data: { behavior: "autocomplete" }, class: "form-control" %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <%= form.button "Search", class: "btn btn-outline-success form-control" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
           <% end %>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works :)
JFYI - in the button line in your answer there is  ' %> too much

Comment: great, i just corrected, if you have time please make this answer